# iOS Core Data : NSBatchUpdateRequest not updating data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a messages in core data that i want to update via batchrequest

```
    if(messages.count > 0)
    {
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Messages" inManagedObjectContext:dbHandler.managedObjectContext];
        NSBatchUpdateRequest *request= [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactId==%@ and groupId==0",contactId];
        request.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType;
        request.propertiesToUpdate = @{
                                   @"status" : @(5)
                                   };
        NSError * errorSave = nil;
        NSBatchUpdateResult *updateResult = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[dbHandler.managedObjectContext executeRequest:request error:&errorSave];
        NSLog(@"Error(IF_ANY) : %@ :: %i objects updated", errorSave.description, updateResult.result,updateResult.result);
    }
```

i'm getting 2 objects updated but when i tried to fetch objects again i'm getting old values. what wrong i'm doing?

screenshot my DB
[image]

Comment: what does your core data stack look like? do the value appear correct if you quit the app and restart?

Comment: its even not updating at runtime

Comment: what does your core data stack look like?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: how many managedObjectContexts do you have? what are their relationships? do you use parent-child relationships? do you use NSPersistentContainer?

Comment: Im not really sure, but you can try this after execute update : context.refreshAllObjects()